# Slack Variables Destroy Convexity?

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-geometry

How do slack variables destroy convexity? Suppose we have a convex optimization problem

$$
\min_{x \in D} f(x) \\
\textrm{subject to} \quad g_{i}(x) \leq 0\\
$$

Why does transforming the problem into

$$
\min_{x \in D, s \in R^{n}} f(x) \\
\textrm{subject to} \quad g_{i}(x) + s_{i} = 0 \\
\quad s_{i} \geq 0
$$

Destroy convexity when $g_{i}(x)$ is not affine or linear?

Comment: Because the constraint $g_i(x) + s_i = 0$ is nonconvex.

Comment: But $g_{i}(x)$ was convex to begin with. So why does adding $s_{i}$ make it non-convex

Comment: Initially there was an inequality constraint $g_i(x) \leq 0$. Now there’s an *equality* constraint involving a nonconvex function. In a convex problem, the only equality constraints allowed are linear equality constraints.

Comment: If $h$ is convex, then $\{x \mid h(x) \leq 0 \}$ is a convex set. But $\{x \mid h(x) = 0 \}$ is usually not a convex set. In a convex problem, $x$ must be constrained to belong to a convex set.

Comment: Ah I get it now, makes perfect sense. Both $h(x)$ and $-h(x)$ must be convex, hence only affine equality constraints. Thanks